# JavaScript Substring missing characters?

Tags: javascript, string, substring

I am trying to use substring to differentiate between data in JavaScript. 
The raw data I am pulling is:

The code I am using is

```js
var contents = '0.! 3.0011632! \
0.01! 2.9417362! ';

var lastPosition = 0;
var count = 0;
//This code will continue looking for ! until it reaches three occurances
while (count < 3) {
  //contents is a string variable that contains all data.
  console.log(lastPosition);
  console.log(contents.indexOf("!", lastPosition + 1));
  console.log(contents.substr(lastPosition + 1, contents.indexOf("!", lastPosition + 1)));
  lastPosition = contents.indexOf("!", lastPosition + 1);
  count++;
}
```

The problem is the output I am getting is:

```
0 //start
3 //end
0.! //#
3 //start
14 //end
3.0011632! //#
14 //start
23 //end 
0.01! 2.9417362! //#
```

As you can see its not properly locating the ! at the third cycle. This continues with more data and it eventually starts missing more and more !'s. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: can you explain 'contents', or better yet, add the code that sets the 'contents' variable?

Comment: contents is a string that contains all of the data. Its somewhat large.

Comment: Your code doesn't produce the same output you say. Is that the real code?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Spelling is now fixed thanks. I have only used a regex to ignore certain characters of combination of characters in java. Could you give an example here as to how it would break up the string a way that makes it so I can rip out individual data points. Thanks.

Comment: @DWigley Use a loop that searches for the regexp `/[^!]*!/g`

Comment: @Barmar I annotated it to make it easier to read.

Comment: I'm not talking about the annotations, the strings and positions are different. Click on Run Code Snippet and see.

Comment: @Barmar That is the output that chrome gives me when I run this locally. Just noticed the differences. Either way it is still skipping the third !. I am not sure why the indices are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression to match a string that ends with `!`. The `g` modifier makes it match all the occurrences and return an array of the matches. Then I use `.slice()` to get just the first 3.

```js
var contents = '0.! 3.0011632! \
0.01! 2.9417362! ';
var matches = contents.match(/[^!]*!/g).slice(0, 3);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. How would you make the 3 used dynamic so I can use it until I reach the end of the file? I have a lot of data and the counter I used at 3 was arbitrary to just test the logic.

Comment: Use a variable instead of `3`.

Comment: Or if you don't really need to limit the number of matches, don't call `.slice`.